# HTML not loading CSS file

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I am completely stumped as to why this doesn't work. It seems the HTML file can't load the CSS for some reason, even though both are in the same directory. Any idea what might be the problem?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"> Hello </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    background-image: url(images/bg3.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0px 1px 0px;
    font-family: "Georgia", "Times", serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main{
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

The above doesn't work. Adding the css inline in index.html works fine though

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        background-color: #F9F9F9;
        background-image: url(images/bg3.png);
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0px 1px 0px;
        font-family: "Georgia", "Times", serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #main {
        margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
        width: 1000px;
        min-height: 500px;
        padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    }
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"> Hello </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are both files in the same directory? Can you access both files by simply changing the filename (e.g. http://example.com/index.html -> http://example.com/style.css)? Have you tried an absolute path (`/style.css`) instead?

Comment: Which browser are you using? have you already checked the file permission of style.css? Have you tried to validate the css so to check for parsing issues?

Comment: Add a type="text/css" if it still fails F12 developer tools, look at the network monitor, it the .css url requested? is it 200 ok?

Answer (score 26):

Add

```
type="text/css"
```

to your link tag

While this may no longer be necessary in modern browsers the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) declared this a required attribute.

> type = content-type [CI]
>
> This attribute specifies the style sheet language of the element's
> contents and overrides the default style sheet language. The style
> sheet language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/css").
> **Authors must supply a value for this attribute; there is no default
> value for this attribute.**

Comment: boilerplate (h5bp) doesn't use that attribute and it works fine too.

Comment: type="text/css" is the default. Its not needed to add it.

Comment: The type attribute was non-optional in HTML4 [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) and so some olders browsers may treat it as such.

Comment: I new to web devolopment, and recently im facing a issue with type="text/css". My problem is when I entered type="text/css"  stylesheet my web page does not work with components which i used to build the webpage. but when i removed the type="text/css" it works perfectly. Anyone knows why I'm facing the issue when i use type="text/css"?

Answer (score 16):

Check both files in the same directory 
and then try this

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

As per you said your both files are in same directory. 1. index.html and 2. style.css

I have copied your code and run it in my local machine its working fine there is no issues.

According to me your browser is not refreshing the file so you can refresh/reload the entire page by pressing CTRL + F5 in windows for mac CMD + R.

Try it if still getting problem then you can test it by using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) tool for firefox.

For IE8 and Google Chrome you can check it by pressing F12 your developer tool will pop-up and you can see the Html and css.

Still you have any problem please comment so we can help you.

Answer (score 10):

You have to add `type="text/css"` you can also specify `href="./style.css"` which the `.` specifies the current directory

Comment: I don´t know why, but adding the dot help me.

Comment: This can happen especially on Linux. You also need to write ./ in front of a program or script you want to run in your current directory, unless that happens to be in your path, e.g. ./myscript, to execute myscript. Linux will not look by default in the current dir.
I think it may be a security issue to add the current directory (.) to $PATH.
It is best to always add ./ for files in current directory, so it will work on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Working on a Mac and the dot helped me too. Tried everything for hours and turns out the problem was a simple ./

Comment: Thank you all for the dot comments! I'm on a Mac and the dot ./ helped me too.

Answer (score 6):

I have struggled with this same problem (Ubuntu 16.04, Bluefish editor, FireFox, Google Chrome.

Solution:  Clear browsing data in Chrome "Settings > Advanced Settings > Clear Browsing Data", 
In Firefox, "Open Menu image top right tool bar 'Preferences' > Advanced ", look for this image in the menu:
Cached Web Content click the button "Clear Now".
Browser's cache the .css file and if it has not changed they usually won't reload it.  So when you change your .css file clear this web cache and it should work unless a problem exists in your .css file.
Peace, 
Stan

Answer (score 5):

Your css file should be defined as UTF-8. Put this in the first line of you css file.

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Comment: When I entered website url like this [www.someURL.com] some parts of css didn't loaded but without [www] worked fine, after setting [@charset "UTF-8";] It works great for both of them, thanks alot dude.

Answer (score 4):

With HTML5 all you need is the `rel`, not even the `type`.

`<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>`

Comment: The `</link>` closing tag is not required.

Answer (score 4):

Well I too had the exactly same question. And everything was okay with my `CSS` link. ***Why html was not loading the `CSS` file was due to its position (as in my case).***

Well I had my custom `CSS` defined in the wrong place and that is why the webpage was not accessing it. Then I started to test and place the CSS link to different place and voila it worked for me.

I had read somewhere that we should place **`custom CSS`** right after **`Bootstrap CSS`** so I did but then it was not loading it. So I changed the position and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure your `link` tag's `media` attribute has a valid value, in my case, I was using **WordPress CMS** and passed the boolean value `true` in the media field so it showed like that.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" media="1">
```

That's why it was giving error. 
There are three main attributes on which the css style loading depends.

1. Make sure that your `link` tag's relation `rel` attribute's value must be valid for a css file i.e. `stylesheet`.
2. Make sure that your `link` tag's target `href` attribute's value must be pointing to a valid an existing Cascading Stylesheet file. Like in your case it's `./style.css`.
   Remember that you can use both absolute and relative paths in the `href` attribute's value. That means if your file `style.css` is present at the root i.e. `/` then you can also use `/style.css` in the `href` attribute's value or else if the file is present in the same directory in which your HTML file is present then you can use `./style.css` as the value in your `link` tag's `href` attribute's value.
3. Make sure that your `link` tag's `media` attribute should be one of the following.

   1. For every device you can use the `all` keyword as your `media` attributes's value.
   2. For PC's and laptops only you can use the `screen` as your `media` attribute's value.
   3. For webpage prints you can use the `print` keyword as your `media` attributes's value. Note that it also applies when you press the **Print Screen** button to capture the screen's image.
   4. At last for screen readers you can use the `speech` keyword as your `media attribute's value.

By following these rules your HTML structure for `link` tag will be.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
```

Make sure that the browser actually makes the request and doesn't return a 404.

Answer (score 3):

I found myself out here looking for an answer and figured out that my issue was a missing character - spelling is important.

```
<link href="tss_layout.css" rel=styleheet" />
```

once I put the s in the middle of stylesheet - worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

After digging and digging on this issue, for me it was solved by Johannes on another thread: [Local CSS file is not loading from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954429/local-css-file-is-not-loading-from-html)

> The `type` attribute in your `link` tag has typographical quote
>   characters: `type=“text/css”`. Try to change these to "plain" quotes
>   like `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same issue,

For Chrome and Firefox but everything was working how it should in internet explorer. I found that making the CSS file UTF-8 made it work for chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and tested different ways to solve it.

Eventually I understood that my index.htm file had been saved with **"Unicode"** encoding (for using Farsi characters in my page) while my .css file had been save with **"ANSI"** format.

I changed the encoding of my .css file to **"Unicode"** with Notepad and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is valuable, but I will leave this here for others. Making sure that "Anonymous Authentication" was set to "Enabled" loaded my CSS file correctly.

To do that in Visual Studio 2019:

1. Select your solution's name, right click, and hit "properties"
2. Navigate to the "Properties" frame, typically in the bottom right corner
3. Ensure that "Anonymous authentication" is set to "Enabled" as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is *another* cause to add to the collection on this page. In this code...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" media="screen">
```

...I **misspelled `rel`** as `ref`.

Comment: What does `rel` stand for? The _**rel**ationship_ that the linked file has to the current parent file.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.. my code was working fine but suddenly css sheets stopped working.. after some detection I found out that somehow the MIME of style sheet was changed from `type="text/css"` to "text-css".. Idk how they were changed since the code was working few hours ago but however I changed it and it worked fine. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well I faced this issue today and as workaround (not the best) I did below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="testWeb/scripts/inline.31e1fb380eb7cf3d75b1.bundle.js"></script>
```

where `testWeb` is my root app folder in my htdoc dir. in windows (using xampp) or in /var/www/html directory  as for some reason I do not know yet

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/inline.31e1fb380eb7cf3d75b1.bundle.js"></script>
```

not loading while html index file beside scripts folder in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a 'special' case but was fiddling with this piece of code:

ForceType application/x-httpd-php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

As a quick test for extentionless file handling, when a similar problem occurred.

Some but not all php files thereafter treated the css files as php and thus succesfully loaded the css but not handled it as css, thus zero rules were executed when checking f12 style editor.

Perhaps something similar might occur to any-one else here and this tidbit might  help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem but resolved changing the Style.css to style.css  Because of this name caps letter "S"change it was throwing 404 error we won't notice small changes in my system it was working but  when I hosted in cloud it was throwing this error make sure this all being checked after uploading in cloud

Answer (score 0):

i have the same probleme, i always change the "style.css" to "styles.css" or any other name
and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you explain why this might have worked for you? Could it have been caching an attempt on the file before it was loaded and changing the name bypassed that? Adding explanation will help make it clear if this answer is applicable to the eight year old question.

Comment: i think that not all of us have the same issue, but my little solution will make in evidence that the problem is caused by cache

Answer (score 0):

HTML was not loading my css because i had placed the style.css in template folder rather it should be in static folder . After replacing my file to static folder it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Use the following steps to load .CSS file its very simple.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_here.css">`

note: 1--> don't forget to write "stylesheet" in rel attribute.
      2--> use correct path e.g: D:\folder1\forlder2\folder3\file.css"

Now where ever directory you are in, you can load your .css file exactly path you mention.

Regards! Muhammad Majid.

Comment: Can't think of a good reason to use absolute paths though. Probably a better way to navigate whatever situation causes you to do that.

Answer (score -2):

guys the best thing to try is to refreash the whole website by pressing **ctrl + F5** on mac it is **CMD + R**

Comment: Sharing answers should be by code for such questions.

Comment: Hi @Za3tar , it's fair to assume that the user has attempted this. It's also not a permanent solution that end users can apply.

Answer (score -4):

Add type="text/css"
It worked for me.

Comment: This same answer has already been given three times 5 years ago. What extra value does this answer provide?