# Local CSS file is not loading from HTML

Tags: html, css

after a few hours of searching through the forums and trying things, I've got the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tester123</title>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type=“text/css” />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> What the what? </h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph. Hooray!</p>
    <div class="trial">What text is this?</div>
    <p>Oh hello. The CSS thing is frustrating hey?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm trying to get the CSS to load in Chrome (from a mac). I've got the css (style1.css) and this file in the same folder (all just loading from my computer), I've cleared the cache, I don't see anything loading in the Chrome Inspector (Sources) about the CSS and I'm stuck for any ideas. I opened up the source and it seems to link through great there. I have quadruple checked file names and types, but I have nothing. Thoughts?

Comment: How do you know that the file is not loaded? Do you get any errors? Maybe your class `trial` is not correctly defined. Post the content of the css file.

Comment: yes it's the quotes in type attribute . however you can delete type attribute since html5 default value for style sheet is css so no need for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type` attribute in your `link` tag has typographical quote characters: `type=“text/css”`. Try to change these to "plain" quotes like `type="text/css"`

Comment: Done! I knew it would be something simple! Thank you very much!!

Comment: I suggest you use a decent HTML editor. Unexpected characters are easily resolved through a quick visual on syntax coloration.