# My viewer.html won't load any css and jss files

Tags: html, css, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to view pdf in my website. However, the viewer.html won't load the viewer.css, pdf.js, and viewer.js. My viewer.html is in the same directory as my viewer.css and viewer.js. The pdf.js is in build directory. My viewer html won't load all these files.

I've tried the solution listed in here : [HTML not loading CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480773/html-not-loading-css-file). But nothing helped.

This is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./viewer.css">
<script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="./viewer.js"></script>
```

Chrome throw error 404 on these three files. I'm using Coldfusion and I'm putting pdf.js on the iframe, could that be the reason?

[image: Edit#1: My folder structure]
[image: Edit#2 : Console error]

Comment: use `../` for the path

Comment: in scr just add this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webodf/ViewerJS/master/viewer.js. if it works for you then copy the content and paste it in seperate js file

Comment: @Amr I've tried <script src="raw.githubusercontent.com/webodf/ViewerJS/master/viewer.js."></script>. It still won't load

Comment: @SaiManoj, I've tried this as well, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you please share the google chrome console error screenshot?

Comment: @AnkushJain, I've updated my question

Comment: Screenshot simply says that it is expecting the files in eDoc folder but unable to find them there. I will still recommend you to inspect elements on viewer.html page & find these links. Then try to open these links in a new tab. By this, you will come to know where these links are pointing at. And you can update the path in viewer.html & again reload the page & repeat the same activity until you get accurate paths.

Answer (score 2):

try this  ../viewer.css instead of ./viewer.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../viewer.css">
<script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="../viewer.js"></script>
```

Comment: if your css and html on the same level then only use viewer.css instead of ../viewer.css

Comment: file path issue

Comment: I've updated my question with an image. The ones with arrows are folders, and the ones with tilde is the file name

Answer (score 0):

As both `css` and `js` are in the same folder of your `html` file, you can directly use as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="viewer.css">
<script src="viewer.js"></script>
```

`pdf` is in different folder, so you need to come out of the current folder using `../` and apply the path for that. So it would be `../build/pdf.js`. Which means come back from the `html` file folder and go to the folder where `pdf.js` is present(that is inside the `build` folder)

```
<script src="../build/pdf.js"></script>
```

Hope you got this cleared

Comment: I've tried this, and it still doesn't work. However, I've tried bringing the html file outside the web folder and into the main folder, and it calling the css file. The only issue there, it is still not calling the pdf.js file in build folder.