# How do i properly link my css and html file together, inspect element says "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: html, css, directory

I've tried all the methods from [HTML not loading CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480773/html-not-loading-css-file) but they don't seem to work. When I tried to inspect the element on chrome, they tell me

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" .

**Here is my file structure**

C>DevProject>index.html 
and in my index.html there are two items one "index" which is my HTML folder, clicking it opens the website. And another item " style" which is my CSS file, clicking it opens notepad with the code

**Here is the code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Test Title</title>
     <link href="/style.css/"type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>H1 text</h1>
    <p>I'm learning to code on Codecademy! My goals include:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Goal 1</li>
      <li>Goal 2</li>
      <li>Goal 3</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the CSS code**

```css
* {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }


  h1 {
    color: SeaGreen;
  }


  p, 
  li {
    font-size: 18px;
  }


  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

I have also tried changing to `href="DevProject/index.html/style.css/"` but "Following the link" through VS code gives me the

> Unable to read file 'c:\DevProject\index.html\DevProject\index.html\style.css\

I ensured that the encoding is UTF-8

I have also tried separating the CSS and HTML file like

```
Devproject>style.css>style
```

but same error

Comment: Try `href="style.css"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a simple mistake, yet one that I've seen beginners make many times.

I'd recommend you start by removing the trailing slash at the end of your stylesheet reference.

If you have your stylesheet in the same directory as your index.html file, then do it as you see below. If you have your stylesheet inside of a css folder, then you can simply change it to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`. Additionally, the `type="text/css"` isn't necessary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Test Title</title>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>H1 text</h1>
    <p>I'm learning to code on Codecademy! My goals include:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Goal 1</li>
      <li>Goal 2</li>
      <li>Goal 3</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.