# The HTML file is not loading CSS file or images when I try opening it directly by click it but it's loading perfectly when I open it with vs code

Tags: html, css, web

When I try to open my html file directly by clicking on it, it's not loading the CSS file or images but when I open it with VS code live server it working fine. The images and stylesheet is on different files

here is the code :
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS files/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"> <meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: When you directly click on the html file, go to inspect page and check the link tag you provided. If you hover over the `href` attribute it will show what file location it is pointing to. I think in your case it might be pointing to the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16643104/22147483.
The href attribute in your code appears to use an absolute path.

Edit.: Try adding a './' before the path to the file to use a relative path.

Comment: Link only answers should be updated to include the important/relevant information from the link (in case the link ever breaks in future)

Comment: @Harrison answers edited...